# Table Cell Editor in a calendar

Tags: java, swing, tablecelleditor

I'm making a calendar in Eclipse and I want to able to edit the cells, adding events etc. Right now, I can write stuff in the cells, but it doesn't look pretty. I figure I need a table cell editor, but I don't really know how to write one.
Does anyone feel like explaining it a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html it goes overs table cell editors and renderers.